# Count value between 2 date ranges

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, countif

I was able to count how many occurrences of dates between 2 date ranges, however now I having difficulty counting how many times Yes occurs between 2 date ranges.

this formula works for counting how many times a date range occurs
where I23 and I24 are the dates in the range (11/30 - 12/15)

`=COUNTIFS(non_activated_accounts_100112!J2:K4000, ">="&$I$23,non_activated_accounts_100112!$J$2:$K$4000,"<="&$I$24)`

This does a great job of counting how many instances of dates showing between the two dates. however I would like to add an additional check column J:2:4000 for "yes", and get result of how many instances of "yes" are there between the 2 dates.

Comment: I have tried =SUMPRODUCT(('Load Entry'!$N$4:$N$563="Yes")*('Load Entry'!$N$4:$N$563>=$A$28)*('Load Entry'!$N$4:$N$563>=$A$27))

Comment: I posted an answer but I see you have different ranges - in your first COUNTIFS you are looking at 2 columns for dates (J and K) - are there dates in both? COUNTIFS requires all ranges to be the same size so you can't have date ranges as two columns and "Yes" range as one - in that case SUMPRODUCT might be better....but can you have a single row where J and K both have a date in your range, if so do you want to count it twice?

Comment: Yes dates are in both - 1st call column J, last call or attempt column K, both need to be looked at and if column N = "Yes" count,

Comment: =COUNTIFS(non_activated_accounts_100112!N2:N4000,Yes,non_activated_accounts_1001‌​12!J2:K4000,">="&$I$23,non_activated_accounts_100112!$J$2:$K$4000,"<="&$I$24) Gives me a #Value error – not sure where the problem is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally better to stick to COUNTIFS, it's more efficient, - you can add more conditions, i.e......

`=COUNTIFS('Load Entry'!$N$4:$N$563,"Yes",'Load Entry'!$N$4:$N$563,">="&$A$28,'Load Entry'!$N$4:$N$563,"<="&$A$27)'

......**But** if you have 2 columns of dates and only one "yes" column then COUNTIFS won't work because all the ranges need to be the same size, so back to SUMPRODUCT.....

Can you count any row twice (if both dates in that row are within the date range and "Yes" appears in that row)? If so try this version

`=SUMPRODUCT((non_activated_accounts_100112!J2:K4000>=$I$23)*(non_activated_accoun‌​ts_100112!$J$2:$K$4000<=$I$24)*(non_activated_accoun‌​ts_100112!$N$2:$N$4000="yes"))`

....or if each row should only be counted once at most.....

`=SUMPRODUCT(((non_activated_accounts_100112!J2:J4000>=$I$23)*(non_activated_accoun‌​ts_100112!$J$2:$J$4000<=$I$24)+(non_activated_accounts_100112!K2:K4000>=$I$23)*(non_activated_accoun‌​ts_100112!$K$2:$K$4000<=$I$24)>0)*(non_activated_accoun‌​ts_100112!$N$2:$N$4000="yes"))`

That second one splits out columns J and K .....

Comment: I'm using the following =COUNTIFS(non_activated_accounts_100112!J2:K4000,">="&$I$23,non_activated_accounts_100112!$J$2:$K$4000,"<="&$I$24)&non_activated_accounts_100112!N2:N3000="Yes"      and it return a "false" as result rather than 5

Comment: =COUNTIFS(non_activated_accounts_100112!N2:N4000,Yes,non_activated_accounts_100112!J2:K4000,">="&$I$23,non_activated_accounts_100112!$J$2:$K$4000,"<="&$I$24)      Gives a #Value error

Comment: For differently sized ranges COUNTIFS doesn't work as per my comment above - I edited my answer for SUMPRODUCT solution

Comment: I get #REF! when trying to use Sumproduct - =SUMPRODUCT((non_activated_accounts_100112!$J$2:$J$4000=I23)*(non_activated_accoun‌​ts_100112!$J$2:$J$4000=I24)*(non_activated_accoun‌​ts_100112!$N$2:$N$4000="yes"))

Comment: I think something went wrong with the sheet name - when I pasted from here I got the same error, there's no problem with the formula, in essence, might be some odd characters when you copy from here - please try re-typing the sheet name, or to simplify things just put the formula on the sheet with the data then you can use a shorter version like `=SUMPRODUCT((J2:K4000>=$I$23)*($J$2:$K$4000<=$I$24)*($N$2:$N$4000="yes"))`    for testing purposes at least that might be simpler.....